# redirect Facebook canvas app to facebook page: white screen

Tags: facebook, canvas

I am trying to redirect the user from my Facebook Canvas app to a Facebook page, but I get a white screen. see screen capture.

Nothing appears in the error log of my Apache server.

Everything runs normally in the web app, outside of the Facebook Canvas.

[image]

Comment: Even though you failed to post any relevant code, my powers tell me that you did redirect _inside_ the iframe, and since Facebook forbids their pages from being displayed in any kind of (i)frame via X-Frame-Options, your browser only shows a white page. (But I am pretty sure at least the browser console had a message in that regard.) If you want to redirect out of the iframe, you should use `top.location.href=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write

```
<a  href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_top"  >FB </a>
```